# How do I perform a text search of a Squeak 3.7 image?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I have an image that runs on the 3.7 version of Squeak - I'd like to do a text search for strings and fragments of strings, over all classes, categories and selectors in the image. Is there a built in tool I can use for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"method source containing it" (mentioned by Alexandre Jasmin) will include class comments, strings, selectors, and method source.

If the string might be contained in a method protocol name, I think you'd have to check programmatically.  Something like:

```
Smalltalk allClasses select: [ :c |
    c organization categories anySatisfy: [: cat |
        '*substring*' match: cat ] ].
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the text that you want to search for (generally from a browser or workspace).
2. Shift-Yellow Click on the text to show up a context menu.

That menu will contains among other things some advanced search options for the selected text string:

- selectors containing it
- method strings with it
- method source with it
- class names containing it
- class comments with it
- change sets with it

Comment: So if I want to do a thorough search I have to start up each of the searches separately?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Are you searching for strings manually or programmatically. Also when you say *"over all classes, categories and selectors"* are you talking about classes, categories and selectors **names** or just about searching in the **source** for all methods in all classes? The *"method source with it"* search can yield good results if you don't know what kind of search you need but you generally have some idea of what you are looking for in the first place.

Comment: I'm looking for *all* references to a substring, from the image. This includes names, and sources. Imagine running a grep against the image, but somewhat nicer looking.